# Difference between Git and GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have recently added a new project to Git using Eclipse, but do not see the project appear in my GitHub account.

Why do they have the same account information and different repositories?

Isn't Git and GitHub the same thing?

Comment: have a look at http://pedrorijo.com/blog/git-init/#what-is-not-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the basics of Git and GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816424/understanding-the-basics-of-git-and-github)

Comment: explanation about whats difference in Git and GitHub https://medium.com/gitmadeeasy/difference-between-git-and-github-306cc4cad48f

Comment: "The difference between git and GitHub is the same as the difference between porn and PornHub"

Answer (score 403, accepted):

**Git** is a revision control system, a tool to manage your source code history.

**GitHub** is a hosting service for Git repositories.

So they are not the same thing: **Git** is the **tool**, **GitHub** is the **service for projects that use Git**.

To get your code to GitHub, [have a look here](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo).

Comment: Most notably, GitHub is a consequence of the existance of git and not the only hosting service.

Comment: Also, you don't *have* to use a remote service like github if all you want is version control - local git is just fine for that. Remote repositories are for backup and collaboration.

Comment: Note that you can create a remote git repository in many web servers like webfaction vs heroku. It's a bit harder to configure that github, but cheaper for big teams.

Comment: checkout this comparison to know more about Git Hosting Services. https://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-hosting-services-compared/

Comment: I think the use of the words "tool" and "service" is ambiguous to people unfamiliar with the issue (i.e., people googling this question). Perhaps "Git is a technology for managing source code, while GitHub is one of many products that provide git as a service for code you host with them."

Comment: Like github you have other providers like Gitlab, Bitbucket, Sourceforge etc...

Answer (score 71):

In the SVN analogy, Git replaces SVN, while GitHub replaces SourceForge :P

If this project of yours is new, then you can still commit to your local Git, then you can *push* to GitHub later on. You will need to add your GitHub repo as a 'remote repository' in your Git setup.

They seem to have something for Eclipse users : http://eclipse.github.com/

Otherwise, if you are new to Git : http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: What are the alternative to using an online GITHUB?

Comment: @variable You mean something like a local Git repository, or a self-hosted Git server like GitLab?

Comment: Like github you have other providers like Gitlab, Bitbucket, Sourceforge etc..

Answer (score 70):

What is [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29):

> "Git is a free and open source distributed **version control system** designed to handle everything from small to very large projects with speed and efficiency"

Git is a distributed peer-peer version control system. Each node in the network is a peer, storing entire repositories which can also act as a multi-node distributed back-ups. There is no specific concept of a central server although nodes can be head-less or 'bare', taking on a role similar to the central server in centralised version control systems.

What is [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub):

> "GitHub is a **web-based** Git repository **hosting service**, which offers all of the distributed revision control and source code management (SCM) functionality of Git as well as adding its own features."

Github provides access control and several collaboration features such as wikis, task management, and bug tracking and feature requests for every project.

You do **not need** GitHub to use Git.

GitHub (and any other local, remote or hosted system) can all be peers in the same distributed versioned repositories within a single project.

Github  allows you to:

- Share your repositories with others.
- Access other user's repositories.
- Store remote copies of your repositories (github servers) as backup
  of your local copies.

Comment: tell me why git is called distributed? just because git store change set in local pc ? please clarify this distributed word significance because i am new to git. thanks

Comment: Do you need Git to use GitHub?

Answer (score 29):

Git — The version control tool that GitHub is built on top of.

GitHub — Our company and the name of our software. We build software and websites to help you interact with Git repositories in a nice way.

GitHub.com — The website you log into to view repositories online.

GitHub Desktop — An application that you can install on your computer to help you synchronize local code with GitHub.com.

source: https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/

Answer (score 19):

There are a number of obvious differences between [Git and GitHub](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Git-vs-GitHub-What-is-the-difference-between-them).

Git itself is really focused on the essential tasks of version control. It maintains a commit history, it allows you to reverse changes through [reset](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-a-git-reset-and-push-to-remote-works-on-previous-local-commits) and [revert](https://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/How-to-git-revert-a-commit-A-simple-undo-changes-example) commands, and it allows you to share code with other developers through push and pull commands. I think those are the essential features every developer wants from a DVCS tool.

[image: Git versus GitHub Comparison Chart]

**No Scope Creep with Git**

But one thing about [Git](https://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Five-basic-Git-commands-every-beginner-needs-to-know) is that it is really just laser focused on source code control and nothing else. That's awesome, but it also means the tool lacks many features organizations want. For example, there is no built-in user management facilities to authenticate who is connecting and committing code. Integration with things like Jira or [Jenkins](https://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Need-a-CI-tool-Heres-a-Jenkins-tutorial-for-beginners) are left up to developers to figure out through things like hooks. Basically, there are a load of places where features could be integrated. That's where organizations like GitHub and GitLab come in.

**Additional GitHub Features**

GitHub's primary 'value-add' is that it provides a cloud based platform for Git. That in itself is awesome. On top of that, GitHub also offers:

- simple task tracking
- a GitHub desktop app
- online file editing
- branch protection rules
- pull request features
- organizational tools
- interaction limits for hotheads
- emoji support!!! :octocat: :+1:

So GitHub really adds polish and refinement to an already popular DVCS tool.

**Git and GitHub competitors**

Sometimes when it comes to differentiating between Git and GitHub, I think it's good to look at who they compete against. Git competes on a plane with tools like Mercurial, Subversion and RTC, whereas GitHub is more in the SaaS space competing against cloud vendors such as GitLab and Atlassian's BitBucket.

**No GitHub Required**

One thing I always like to remind people of is that you don't need GitHub or GitLab or BitBucket to use Git. Git was released in what, 2005? GitHub didn't come on the scene until 2007 or 2008, so big organizations were doing distributed version control with Git long before the cloud hosting vendors came along. So Git is just fine on its own. It doesn't need a cloud hosting service to be effective. But at the same time, having a PaaS provider certainly doesn't hurt.

**Working with GitHub Desktop**

By the way, you mentioned the mismatch between the repositories in your GitHub account and the repos you have locally? That's understandable. Until you've connected and done a pull or a fetch, the local Git repo doesn't know about the remote GitHub repo. Having said that, GitHub provides a tool known as the [GitHub desktop](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Test-Git-command-basics-on-the-GitHub-Desktop-app) that allows you to connect to GitHub from a desktop client and easily load local Git repos to GitHub, or bring GitHub repos onto your local machine.

[image: GitHub Desktop]

I'm not overly impressed by the tool, as once you know Git, these things aren't that hard to do in the Bash shell, but it's an option.

[image: The fight between Git and GitHub]

Comment: "Git vs. GitHub" is comparing apples and oranges. Or rather, apples and tractors.

Answer (score 9):

In simple way we can tell below are the difference between git and git hub and VSTS.

**git**: - Treat git as a engine/technology to achieve source version control to our project. Unlike TFS (again a centralized source version control ) git is distributed version control technology. That means git it actually does not mandate to have any server. Through git technology we can make our own local machine as a source code repository not required to have a centralized server always(in large scale it can have Microsoft server to push and keep our project source code). But with SVN and TFS kind version control, it is mandatory that a server be associated with it.

For example if I am a free-lance developer and I directly report to my client and there is no other developer involved, I need to keep version control of my code to roll back(any version) and commit my codes and I don't have budget to get a server and I don't have time to install and use other server in my machine as TFS server and TFS client. So, the optimal way is to install git engine and use my local machine as a repository for version controlling by git.

**GitHub**: - as I said previously git is a technology and used with some command / shell commands , ie git only doesn't have UI. GitHub is online product or online repository which uses git technology for their process and achieve version controls along with other functionalities like bug tracking,Project management, Support ticket management ..etc. In other words Git Hub is a wrapper build on git technology with a UI and other functionalities by other third party firm, it is actually a product owned by somebody or some group based on git technology , where as git is open source, and not marketable product.

**VSTS** : - VSTS is a Microsoft product for online repository keeping source version control which can be treated as an alternate to git hub. Since its of Microsoft , VSTS support both git technology and TFS(TFVC-team foundation version control). Because TFS is another old Microsoft product to achieve this version control.Gradually I assume VSTS will gradually dump TFS as git is the prominent technology in this area and it is open source.

Answer (score 7):

In plain English:

1. They are all source control as we all know.
2. In an analogy, if Git is a standalone computer, then GitHub is a **network** of computers connected by web with bells and whistlers.
3. So unless you open a GitHub acct and **specifically** tell VSC or any editor to use GitHub, you'll see your source code *up-there* otherwise they are only down here, - your local Git.
4. GitHub when used with VSC utilizes Git to complete its operations.

Answer (score 0):

**Git-**
Git is a version control software that you install on your local system. For an individual working on a project alone, Git proves to be excellent software.

**GitHub-**
As mentioned earlier, Git is a version control system that tracks code changes, while GitHub is a web-based Git version control repository hosting service. It provides all of the distributed version control and source code management (SCM) functionalities of Git while topping it with a few of its own features.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, Git is a version control system that lets you manage and keep track of your source code history. GitHub is a cloud-based hosting service that lets you manage Git repositories. If you have open-source projects that use Git, then GitHub is designed to help you better manage them.

Answer (score 0):

In simple:

Git - is local repository.

GitHub - is central repository.

Hope below image will help to understand:
[image: Git and GitHub Difference]

[image: Git and GitHub Difference more details]

Answer (score -3):

Github is required if you want to collaborate across developers. If you are a single contributor git is enough, make sure you backup your code on regular basis