# Relation Between GIT,GitHub and Source Tree

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am newbie to GIT, currently in my project they are using SourceTree. When i studying GIT, GitHub came into picture..

My Confusion is:
1) How GIT is related to SurceTree..?
2) How GIT is related to Github..?
3) Does SourceTree and Github serves same purpose..?

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks

Mahesh

Comment: Git is a linux program, Sourcetree is a git GUI, Github is host for software repositories that can be managed/downloaded via git.  Heres a pretty good start:  https://github.com/GSoft-SharePoint/Dynamite/wiki/Getting-started-with-SourceTree,-Git-and-git-flow

Comment: @Davon: Thanks.. :)
Can i assume that GitHub and SourceTree two different softwares which are used to manage version controlling GUI from GIT..?

Comment: Github is not "software" per say.  It is a web interface and host for repositories.  Sourcetree isn't a host, there isn't much similar between the two.  Sourcetree can be used to access a repository hosted on Github.

Comment: Hope it will clarify more on Git and GitHub difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65527165/7173176

Answer (score 17):

Git is a version control system. Basically a set of data file standards, network protocols and command-line tools. An alternative would be Mercurial, for example. Both of these are open-source software, developed by a world-wide community and not owned by any particular company.

Github is a website/company/service that allows you to host your git repositories so that you don't have to set up your own server. A competitor would be Bitbucket, for example, run by Atlassian.

SourceTree is a GUI application that you can use to work with git if you don't like the command line tools. It is a piece of software that you install on your computer, and it is made by Atlassian.  It can also handle Mercurial repositories.

Comment: Does sourcetree also provide hosting services for your repositories?

Comment: No. SourceTree is a GUI application. But its maker, Atlassian does. They call it Bitbucket.