# Commit history of projects prior to its date of creation on GitHub

Tags: github

What does it mean when base repositories of projects hosted on GitHub have commit history prior to project creation date on GitHub? Also, what does it mean when forks of a project have commit history prior to its creation date on GitHub?

Comment: just checked that it might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321556/difference-between-git-and-github. Leaving my answer in case it doesn't get flagged.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the user that created that repository managed the repo before, outside of GitHub.

Imagine this as a document in Dropbox, you create it today in your computer, you upload it next week to Dropbox:

```
Date of creation: 27th Jan 2015
Data of file creation on Dropbox: 4th Feb 2015
```

This might seem tricky to you because you, if youare not distinguishing git and github. You can have a whole network of git repositories without GitHub.

GitHub provides visualization and great tooling on top of git repos.