# Syncing local non git project with remote git repository having same project

Tags: git, github

I am new at git and github. 
I have a private github repository and same project at my local but It is not git repository. I don't want to clone git repository directly because I already have that project at the local  machine. How can I synchronise local non git repo of same project which have github repository?

Comment: Which version control do you use locally? If the answer is *none*, then create a Git repo and use it.

Comment: First of all git and github are different look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321556/difference-between-git-and-github) for difference. Create a git repo in a directory with `git init` and paste your local project files in that one. Now from github copy cloning address and set that as upstream repo for locally created git repo.

Comment: can you explain more about this "set that as upstream repo for locally created git repo"
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the github repository as a remote (using `git remote add`, [see here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/)). If the local folder and the github repo are the same, a `git pull` should tell you that everything is up-to-date. Otherwise, it should show the changes.

Edit: Ah, it looks like your local folder is not yet a repo. For that, you will need to create a local repository first by using `git init`.

Alternatively, you can also checkout the github repo and simply copy your local changes on top of that.

Comment: That is what I have said in comment