# Relationship between GIT, Bit bucket and source tree

Tags: git

I am new to GIT, currently in my project they are using bitbucket and SourceTree. I am only using bit bucket for cloning project and source tree for taking that project on my local drive.When does GIT come into the picture

My Confusion is:

1. What is the particular use of source tree, bit bucket and GIT?
2. How GIT is related to SurceTree and bit bucket?
3. How GIT is related to Github?

Comment: Have you done any research? This topic has been covered plenty of times in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13321556/248567 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13321556/248567

Answer (score 11):

**1) GIT**

Git is a version control system (VCS) for tracking changes in computer files and coordinating work on those files among multiple people. It is primarily used for software development,[9] but it can be used to keep track of changes in any set of files. As a distributed revision control system it is aimed at speed, data integrity and support for distributed, non-linear workflows.

Git was created by Linus Torvalds in 2005 for development of the Linux kernel, with other kernel developers contributing to its initial development.

As with most other distributed version control systems, and unlike most client–server systems, every Git directory on every computer is a full-fledged repository with complete history and full version tracking abilities, independent of network access or a central server.

**2) GITHUB AND BITBUCKET**

GitHub is a web-based Git or version control repository and Internet hosting service. It offers all of the distributed version control and source code management functionality of Git as well as adding its own features.

Example- like social networking sites ex- facebook , you share your pictures etc.. In similar manner github and bitbucket helps you to share your code and other users to get the your code for their use. they can have copy of your code and make changes as per their need.

**3) SOURCE TREE**
Since GIT is a command-line tool . Sometimes it is hard to remember commands. 
Source Tree is GUI based GIT application tool. It provides an nice visual interface between you and Git, no more command line!

Comment: thank you for the clean information

Answer (score 4):

Git is basically a version control system. It can be used in many different ways but has features to make collaboration on one code base a lot easier and provides "snapshots" of your code at different times to make it easy to revert in case of problems.

SourceTree is basically a GUI that sits on top of Git so you can use an interface instead of using console commands all the time.

Bitbucket and Github basically host your repo online so you can have a backup of it on their servers and this gives easy access so other team members can access it anywhere.