# Git as source code control + Visual Studio, without GitHub

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control, visual-studio-2017

Suppose John and Alice are a team of and they work on a private (not public nor opensource) project.

Actually they are using VS2013 and SVN (TortoiseSVN) as source code repository. They have a server machine with a SVN source control so they can push their changes.

So `J` and `A` are clients and `S` is the (SVN) code source server.

John starts creating a new project with Visual Studio 2017 that a priori uses **Git** as code source control.

Is there a way to use GIT as independent installer for `J`, `A` and `S`, **without** creating a *public* GitHub repository, or a *private (but paid)* **GitHub** repository?

Where, in that case to read about installing the Server GIT version (or it works like the client one)...?

Or maybe is possible to continue to use SVN in the same way with VS 2017?

PS. I say about the GitHub, because just installed GIT setup and the first screen is the following one:

[image]

[image]

Comment: John and Alice should have a look at the [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/). It's free for up to 5 users and offers much more than a simple source code repository.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you focused on *GitHub*? Git is not tied to GitHub in any way. If John and Alice had been using a (private) SVN server and it was working fine for them, they can have a private server with git repos just as easily.

Comment: If you have a (private) server that has ssh access to it and git is installed on it, you can create a bare repo on it (so that no one can work on it, it will be just a repo, no working tree) and you will be able to access it from _other hosts_ by setting it up as a remote... which is a very veeeery simple recipe if you ask me. Other transports are also supported (like https, and stuff). Just google around. There will be plenty of examples out there.

Comment: So, finally John, Alice and Server should install the same git setup, just S to be configured like a server without the working tree

Comment: It's just a matter of having a server that provides some kind of transport that git can use to get access to a repo. A repo on a server is _no_ different from a repo on a client. You can use bare repos on your "client" box.... or you could set up a full blown repo (with working tree) on a server (if you consider it necessary). It's veeeery much a matter of what you want, not what the tool is forcing you to do or have.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I have just installed the GIT installer...

Comment: So, it seems looking at the screens that GITis very linked with GitHub...

Comment: I don't know what git client you are using but if you use plain old "git" from git-scm.com (aka _git_), you will notice it's actually not tied to github. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321556/difference-between-git-and-github

Comment: @Serge you did not installed git but 'GitHub desktop' (that also contains git) that's why it's very tied to github.