# What is the difference between git and Github CLI or gh?

Tags: git, github, github-cli

What is the difference between `git` and GitHub CLI?
Which one should I use, `git` or GitHub CLI or `gh` depending on the situation?
For example, cloning a repository, both [commands](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) [support](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_clone) it. What gives?
I am specifically asking for the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com) not GitHub itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Git and GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321556/difference-between-git-and-github)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**`git`** is used for git in general you can use **Bitbucket** or **GitLab** any provider with it you just add remote and you can push.

But Github CLI is for Github you can manage many features of Github from CLI e.g issues.

I personally prefer git as I am more comfortable and in many offices I don't use Github. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html#_examples

Comment: Thanks, I was confused.

Answer (score 5):

Another difference, since Sept. 2021, is its extensibility.

> ### [Creating GitHub CLI extensions](https://docs.github.com/en/github-cli/github-cli/creating-github-cli-extensions)
>
> GitHub CLI extensions are custom GitHub CLI commands that anyone can create and use. For more information about how to use GitHub CLI extensions, see "[Using GitHub CLI extensions](https://docs.github.com/en/github-cli/github-cli/using-github-cli-extensions)"
>
> You need a repository for each extension that you create. The repository name must start with gh-. The rest of the repository name is the name of the extension. At the root of the repository, there must be an executable file with the same name as the repository. This file will be executed when the extension is invoked.

While you can create aliases with `git` commands, you now can create complexe commands with gh extensions.

Answer (score 5):

As said [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64763276/14098813) that `gh` is for GitHub, literally the description says:

> Work seamlessly with GitHub from the command line.

Regarding about the similar commands of cloning a repositoy (I feel like I remember what I was asking):

- `git clone` has more limited syntax than `gh repo clone` (`gh repo clone OWNER/REPO`)
- using `gh repo clone` to clone a fork and automatically add the GitHub upstream repository