# Adding laravel to an existing project that already runs with laravel on the web

Tags: laravel, installation

Im very new to laravel and ive a project on a server that uses laravel.

How can i download this project and run laravel to it ? I managed to run laravel but it creates a whole new folder etc.

when i tried coppying the project folder to the laravel-created folder i got an error.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain what you mean by adding laravel to a laravel project?!

Comment: i have the source code of a project that runs on laravel. Basicaly i am asking how can i run this source code localy on my pc

Answer (score 0):

Download source code except vendor casus it's extra. Install php and composer. Then use a terminal(cmd in windows) and go to your project and run composer install. Wait till downloading packages complete. For running project type `php artisan serve` and your project is up. If your project had migrations and I think it has actually, run `php artisan migrate` before running serve command. Also check .env file in the root of project and change database credentials with your own. Depending on what dbms that project uses, you should install that DBMS too. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Taking reference to your comment:

> i have the source code of a project that runs on laravel. Basicaly i am asking how can i run this source code localy on my pc

Good, that you have a project that runs on Laravel. You should probably consider to move your project to a central place, maybe [Github](https://github.com/), and from there create a proper workflow for development and further deployment to your (testing, production, ...) systems.

Even if you develop alone it would be a good practice to use git and Github - no, [it is not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321556/difference-between-git-and-github)

To come back to your original question:

> How can i download this project and run laravel to it ? I managed to run laravel but it creates a whole new folder etc.

You don't need to install a new Laravel into an existing Laravel project. Just take the existing one.