# How to collaborate with poeple using Dropbox if I prefer to use Git (Github)?

Tags: git, github, version-control, dropbox, symlink

### Short question:

- Is there tricks from `git`, (or command-line/`Git-bash`/`WSL`_on_Windows), such that I will be hosting the git-repo locally, in wherever I prefer, and have only the *real files* synced **two-ways** between the local git-repo and a Dropbox folder?
- Even shorter: is there a way to push from a local repo to a Git remote, and have the files stay "two-way-synced" to a Dropbox folder **before and after** the push?

At the end of the day, I would like to keep pushing to the remote git-repo as usual. I will push shortly after committing, and would prefer all file-contents from the two sources (the Dropbox folder and the local copy of the Git-repo) to stay synced before and after the commit-push activities. *(I am less confident here as this may go against the philosophy of "staging" my works per each commit.)*

**Clarification**: I do not intend to do anything fancy with Git. I prefer to keep working with the same branch, and to pull/push from/to the same Github repo as the remote. **In particular, I will need to get things to work on *multiple* PCs and a Linux machine**.

#### Unsuccessful attempts:

1. First, I think it is a bad idea to initialize a git-repo inside the `~/Dropbox` folder, as [it creates clutters and thereby, likely, conflicts](https://www.quora.com/If-I-create-a-local-Git-repository-inside-a-Dropbox-folder-would-I-get-access-to-it-from-all-my-machines).
2. I have thought about creating a "Selective-sync" through the Dropbox GUI to simply exclude the `.git` folder. Yet, without such `.git` folder, it is unclear how to establish the local repo on all computers of mine (I do use multiple Windows PC and one more Linux box).
3. I am not good at `symlink`, and have been playing with it a good number of times but failed. If someone were to suggest it, please be precise. Also, I would need it to work across multiple Windows machines and Linux box. I am happy to add more details as long as I get a working demo from you.

#### Backgrounds

Thankfully, my collaborators has improved from the emailing habit of handing off drafts and work-in-progress through piles of zip-files. Nowadays, they are happy with a shared Dropbox folder. Yet, they haven't started to care too much about version control. Quotes from them: "Git on the command-line? It is a joke?" lol.

On the other hand, I have been happy with pushing to Github as my remote repo, and have been doing so for a good number of years. I am used to my git commands, and have devised the following `alias` settings to do so quickly.

```
alias ga='git add -A'
alias gs='git status'
alias gc='git commit -m'
alias gp='git push'
alias gpp='git pull'
```

I am looking for a way to use Git(Github) and Dropbox in harmony. And I am aware of the following knowledge:

- [How to use `git` occasionally when hosting everything on Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122278/git-github-dropbox) ==> I am not a paid user of Dropbox, and my projects may easily overgrow my limit.
- [Details on Git and Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872642/how-to-collaborate-in-a-project-using-git-without-using-github)
- [Brilliant notes on using Dropbox as a Git (remote) repository](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290743/using-dropbox-git-repository)
- [Super convening marking material to pull people from Dropbox to Git (Github)](https://gist.github.com/magicseth/1951984)

Among the three unsuccessful attempts on my end, I am inclined to believe some `symlink` command (or complicated scripts) will do the trick. Looking forward to further instruction from the community. I am tagging as many vision control

Comment: Seriously, dropbox is not an acceptable, professional way of working on software sources. Educate them. If they're afraid of the command line, make them use a git UI like SourceTree.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet. I totally agree with you. Yet, I am the primary programmer of the team, and others are in charge of other aspects. The most sophisticated tasks that are left should be editing `*.tex` documents, which people have been super fluent with. I found [this `git `command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) of potential value. As commented [here](https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/peace-between-git-and-dropbox-with-git-worktree/289), it is good for virtually "separating" the super-large `~/.git` folder from files in other branches that are stored on Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

### Tentative attempt using `git-worktree`?

Inspired by [noamross](https://discuss.ropensci.org/u/noamross)'s [post](https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/peace-between-git-and-dropbox-with-git-worktree/289), the following quote looks applicable to my situation

> With git worktree, you have one or more “linked working trees”
>   (linked directories) connected to the “main working tree” (main
>   directory). Importantly, linked directories do not have .git folders.
>   Instead, they have .git files which point them to the main directory.
>   This means they are much less trouble to sync with Dropbox.

The steps appear to be super relevant, and I feel like experimenting the following:
* Initialize the repo somewhere else;
* As suggested in the [original post](https://discuss.ropensci.org/u/noamross), issue the command `git worktree add -b dropbox ~/Dropbox/project-repo-dropbox` to create the other branch on Dropbox.

#### Remaining documentation for the `git-worktree` method (missing for now)

1. How to replicate the `git worktree` setting on another Windows/Linux machine?
2. Good reference on "branching in Git". I have personally not used branches a lot, and will need to update this post with a complete workflow.
3. Well, a simple answer whether the proposed recipe works or not. (Didn't have the time to try it out yet.)

#### Please advise if you have better ideas :)

Comment: This seems likely to work, to some extent. It means that you can let Dropbox update the added work-tree whenever and however Dropbox likes, and then manually use the added work-tree to update the repository whenever *you* choose. There's a fair bit of manual work involved and, for any use of `git worktree add`, you should be sure you have at least Git 2.15 if possible.

Comment: @torek, thank you for the kind comment. Will I get into trouble if I were to repeat the same `git worktree add` command on multiple Windows PC? After all, there is only one Dropbox destination that I would like to write to.

Comment: Each Windows box needs to have its own local repository. If you're using a shared (network) drive for the local Git repository—I don't know whether this works; I avoid Windows—then each added work-tree would also have to be on its own branch, as there's a `git worktree add` constraint that requires every added work-tree to use a different branch from every other existing work-tree.

Comment: I see the challenge here: although I am more than happy to keep a "real" local copy of the Git repository (somewhere outside Dropbox), chances are that I shall end up creating new branches for each of my Windows/Linux "box"? [Notes on Windows with Git ==> they are working just fine] [Clarification: I am more than happy to restrain from using any other "Network Drive" of any sort. Local copies are physical and *real* :)]

Comment: OK, well, as far as (each) Git is concerned, the local repository (`.git` directory and contents) are to be touched only by Git, and only on *your* machine, which is the center of the universe. :-) So each Windows system's Git is independent, and you're fine there. The only remaining issue will be whether Dropbox fiddling with each system's work-tree functions properly: Git records `stat` data to know if some user (including perhaps Dropbox as a user) has been fussing with the work-tree content, so ... [continued]

Comment: ... so if Dropbox changes a work-tree file, it should change it the same way a user would, making the file's time-stamps increase. If Dropbox tries to keep the time-stamps static, Git could miss a work-tree change (Git will see it if the file's reported `stat` data change, so if the file changes *size* Git will see it).

Comment: I totally agree with your comment that the local repository is the center of the universe :). However, I find it challenging to "think through" establishing the same "Dropbox branch" at exactly the same Dropbox location from "variables universes" ==> after setting up `git worktree` with the tag `-b` to create a new branch on Machine A, how am I going to reproduce the same settings on Machine B? By taking away the flag `-b`?

Comment: Have the systems that *do* have Git, communicate with each other via Git protocols, not Dropbox. That is, use push/fetch to go from Git-enabled system to Git-enabled system.

Comment: I do intend to host local Git repos on 2 Windows machines and 1 Linux machine. Given the current implementation of `git worktree`, am I restricted to keep all the Git-related activities on one machine only?

Comment: No, but you'll want to have the Git-enabled machines use Git protocols and non-Dropbox worktrees to talk to each other. Pick one machine to use to talk to non-Git Dropbox-only systems, add the one worktree there, and use that one machine to do that communication. Otherwise you'll have a maintenance nightmare ("who has the latest?").

Comment: Thank you for raising the concern for "who has the latest"? I should probably restrict myself to working with one local Git repo at a time. Any advise on the specific command to use when I **need** to "move" from one machine to another? [Comment on THE QUESTION: I tend to be dealing with different portions of the project on different machines. Say, I was scarping using the Linux machine, and saving pickles every-other-hour. These hourly-dumped pickles are *ignored*, and only the non-duplicates are pushed. These aggregated pickles are used for analysis elsewhere. ... [continued]

Comment: ... [continued] By "elsewhere", it is usually the Windows laptop that I tend to carry around with me. I will continue from whatever has been scraped so far, and update the analysis in Jupyter Notebook. At the end of the day, I should be writing to different sub-directories from different machines. This worked for me.] I am by far not a "good" programmer, and there are many practices that I need to standardize. @torek, thanks a lot for your patience and guidance. For the particular project that I would **have** to work with Dropbox people, I shall follow your advise and ... [continued]

Comment: ... and keep one local Git repo on a specific machine. After all, it is a good idea to separate projects from each other by distinguishing the work-environment "physically" :) I was asking about the question about "migrating" from one machine to the other, as the manufacturer for my laptop will finally send me the "fixed laptop" after months of debugging. I wanted to setup such Dropbox-branched-from-Git thing on my laptop, both the current loaner one and the one that I bought originally.

Comment: Ah ... well, you're getting well past scenarios I've imagined. I'm not sure I have any good advice for these cases...

Comment: Those were previous "good" cases where well-disciplined asynchronous pushing and pulling from **totally separate directories** did no more than minimum harm. I do take your advise on keeping the scenarios as simple as possible for `git worktree`. Will post a more specific question about establishing the "worktree" for Dropbox across multiple machines. Thanks a lot for walking me through the logics and proper usages @torek :)