# How did Git managed right access before GitHub?

Tags: git, github

For example, I would like to know how a project member is being configured:

How do you decide who can push code and who can not?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

Comment: Github is a glorified proprietary frontend for git. Git does not need it. That being said, I don't really understand the purpose of your question. What are trying to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321556/difference-between-git-and-github

Comment: Github is just a server/remote. There are other remotes like gitlab. A private server could have been used.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816424/understanding-the-basics-of-git-and-github

Comment: If you are looking for a git web ui with user management support that you can host locally, you may want to look into: [GitLab](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-GitLab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are trying to solve is the authentication/authorization in Git, said Git does not have any, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685757/6309).

That means a Git repository hosting service, like GitHub, is free to implement its own authorization strategy, as documented in "[Access permissions on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/access-permissions-on-github)"
[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) has [its own set of rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html).

Should you manage your own Git repository service, you would need to add:

- an authentication layer (SSH or HTTPS server)
- an authorization layer (like **[gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)**)
- or both in one product ([gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/), or [many others](https://alternativeto.net/software/gitea/?platform=self-hosted))

Comment: Without setting authorization through GitHub's API, by default anyone who can clone can also push, am I correct?

Comment: Sort of correct. Like @VonC mentioned is GitHub a service that adds a permission system on top of git. If you were to run your own server with git installed and would decide to share the access to a repo, then everyone with access to that server/repo would be able to clone and push. See the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server#_ssh_access) for more information

Comment: @Elvin Yes: if you have remote access to a Git repository (through one of the [Git supported protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols), like filesystem share, SSH or HTTPS, you can clone and push back. I have edited the answer to add gitolite.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It's a very clear and helpful explanation.